# Load a Amazon S3 file which has colons within the filename through pyspark

Tags: python, amazon-s3, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a S3 bucket which contains multiples files which have colon within their file names.

Example :

```
s3://my_bucket/my_data/en/2015120/batch:222:111:00000.jl.gz
```

I am trying to load this in to a spark RDD and access the first line as follows.

```
my_data = sc.textFile("s3://my_bucket/my_data/en/2015120/batch:222:111:00000.jl.gz")
my_data.take(1)
```

But this throws,

```
llegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:
```

Any suggestions to load these files individually or more preferably as the whole folder

Comment: can you try using * in the file name. like 's3://path/*.gz' . I am using the same thing as you have above and it is working for me.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work by replacing the colons to url encoded format.

i.e.

`:` would be replaced with `%3A`

To double check, click on one of the objects in S3 and see the "link"

[image: S3 Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to use a custom FileSystem implementation, as they did [here (Totango Labs)](http://labs.totango.com/spark-read-file-with-colon/)

The gist of it is that you're bypassing the internal `globStatus` function which tries to interpret the filenames as paths, instead using `listStatus`.  The downside is that while this will allow you to work with S3 URLs with a colon, it will not allow you to specify wildcards in the URL.

```
final Configuration hadoopConf = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration();
hadoopConf.set("fs." + CustomS3FileSystem.SCHEMA + ".impl",
  CustomS3FileSystem.class.getName());

public class CustomS3FileSystem extends NativeS3FileSystem {
  public static final String SCHEMA = "custom";

  @Override
  public FileStatus[] globStatus(final Path pathPattern, final PathFilter filter)
      throws IOException {
    final FileStatus[] statusList = super.listStatus(pathPattern);
    final List<FileStatus> result = Lists.newLinkedList();
    for (FileStatus fileStatus : statusList) {
      if (filter.accept(fileStatus.getPath())) {
        result.add(fileStatus);
      }
    }
    return result.toArray(new FileStatus[] {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please note that in order to access S3, you need to use the `s3n` schema, not just s3, as documented in the Spark [FAQ](http://spark.apache.org/faq.html), otherwise the Hadoop parser [fails](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3257).