# URISyntaxException while using GlobStatus for s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

I am using globStatus to get all the files and directories from a s3 bucket using "*" wildcard
and one of the directory present in the bucket has special character in it (directory name is
**env:**)

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileStatus, FileSystem, Path}


val uri = validatePath("Bucket_path")
val fs = getFs(uri)
val fileStatuses = fs.globStatus(new Path(uri))
```

globStatus is failing because of this directory with below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 4: env:
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:129)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:338)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:202)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.globStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:4253)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.globStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:4233)
... 40 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 4: env:
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2847)
at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2853)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3056)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:746)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:260)
... 50 more
```

Is there an alternate way to use wildcard and get all the files and directories from a bucket.

**edit**
this issue is open on Hadoop Common jira board
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14235

Comment: Have you tried URI encoding the colon?

Comment: I am not sure how to encode it @OneCricketeer

Comment: Java has a class called URLEncoder which may help

Comment: I tried URL encoding but now I am not able to fetch any of the files or directory from the bucket. `val fileStatuses = fs.globStatus(new Path(URLEncoder.encode("bucket_name","UTF-8")))`. Plus is there way to encode URI and not URL using hadoop configuration since encoding has to be applied to individual directories as well and not just for bucket_name @OneCricketeer

Comment: It should work similarly... Or you do a simple string replace. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34093098/load-a-amazon-s3-file-which-has-colons-within-the-filename-through-pyspark

Comment: S3 doesn't have "directories", only prefixes. You'll need to escape the colon and any other special characters that aren't valid file characters